# Rspec test passing only when there's a PUTS in the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, callback

The `puts` statement must be having some kind of weird effect that I'm not seeing here...

I have an `Order` model. There's a callback on the model where the callback requires the model to be fully committed; i.e., I need to use an `after_commit`. However, the determinant of if the callback should run or not requires `ActiveRecord::Dirty` and therefore requires a `before_save` (or `after_save`, but I use `before_save` based on some other non-essential info).

I have combined the two thusly:

```
class Order
  # not stored in DB, used solely to help the before_save to after_commit transition
  attr_accessor :calendar_alert_type, :twilio_alerter

  before_save
    if self.calendar_alert_type.nil?
      if self.new_record?
        self.calendar_alert_type = "create, both"
      elsif self.email_changed?
        self.calendar_alert_type = "update, both" 
      elsif self.delivery_start_changed? || self.delivery_end_changed? || (type_logistics_attributes_modified.include? "delivery")
        self.calendar_alert_type = "update, start"
      elsif self.pickup_start_changed? || self.pickup_end_changed? || (type_logistics_attributes_modified.include? "pickup")
        self.calendar_alert_type = "update, end"
      end
    end

    puts "whatever"
  end

  after_commit do
    if self.calendar_alert_type.present?
      calendar_alert(self.calendar_alert_type) 
    end
  end
end

def calendar_alert(alert_info)
  puts "whatever"
  alert_type = alert_info.split(",")[0].strip
  start_or_end = alert_info.split(",")[1].strip
  if start_or_end == "both"
    ["start","end"].each do |which_end|
      Calendar.send(alert_type, which_end, self.id)
    end
  else
    Calendar.send(alert_type, start_or_end, self.id)
  end
end
```

All of the private methods and the `ActiveRecord::Dirty` statements are working appropriately. This is an example of a spec:

```
it "email is updated" do
  Calendar.should_receive(:send).with("update", "start", @order.id).ordered
  Calendar.should_receive(:send).with("update", "end", @order.id).ordered
  find("[name='email']").set("nes@example.com")
  find(".submit-changes").click
  sleep(1)
end

it "phone is updated" do
  ... #same format as above
end
```

Literally all the specs like the above pass ONLY when EITHER `puts` statements is present. I feel like I'm missing something very basic here, just can't put my finger on it. It's super weird because the `puts` statement is spitting out random text...

*Note, I'm totally aware that `should_receive` should be `expect_to_receive` and that I shouldn't use sleep and that expectation mocks on feature tests aren't good. Working on updating the specs separately from bad code days, but these shouldn't be causing this issue... (feel free to correct me)

Comment: Have you tried to narrow down the problem? Can you shorten the example any further or maybe even create a minimal example?

Comment: BTW, the `do` after `before_save` is missing. Maybe it is just a copy and paste error but it could also be the cause of your problem. In either case, it makes your example code invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior depends on your Rails version. Before Rails 5 you can return anything except `false` value to keep on running. A `false` will abort the `before_*` callback chain. `puts 'whatever'` returns a  nil. So every thing works. Your `if` block seems to return a `false` (custom implemation for `calendar_alert_type`?). In this case the chain is holded.

With Rails 5 you have to `throw(:abort)` to stop callback handling.

Comment: I was thinking the same at first, but this cannot be the reason, because `puts` doesn't return an `truthy` value. `puts` returns `nil` what is `falsey`. See **[docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html#method-i-puts)**

Comment: Rails 4 behaves [slightly different](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.7.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html#module-ActiveRecord::Callbacks-label-Canceling+callbacks): you have to return `false` to stop the callback chain. Anything else, including `nil`, does _not_ stop it.

Comment: @spickermann & Stefan you are both right. I corrected my awnser. Thanks!

Comment: Your explanation seems reasonable, but I can't see how the OP's `before_save` code could return `false`.

Comment: @Stefan maybe a custom implementation for `calendar_alert_type` or the source code is incomplet.

Comment: if self.new_record? != true then it'd return false. thanks for telling me about this!